# How to retrieve multiple values of single column in session

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

Each user on my website has a `reg_id`. There are some `emergency_contact_id`'s associated with this `reg_id`.

For example:

```
EmerContact_id  Reg_id    
  91              1    
  92              1    
  93              1    
  94              1    
  95              1
```

Now I want to store these `EmerContact_id`'s into session like this:

```
Session["Emer1"]    
Session["Emer2"]    
Session["Emer3"]    
Session["Emer4"]    
Session["Emer5"]
```

How can I achieve this?

I am thinking of using:

```
while(reader.read()) { ... }
```

But I don't know how to use it.

Comment: What you need, are you want to store `EmerContact_id` and get the `reg_id` based on that or you want to sore both ids at once?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty i want to store both at once...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MySqlDataReader` and iterate through your results using an index marker, like this.

```
using (MySqlConnection dbConnection = new MySqlConnection("connectionstring"))
{
    dbConnection.Open();

    using (MySqlCommand dbCommand = new MySqlCommand("select EmerContact_id from [Table] order by EmerContact_id asc;", dbConnection))
    {
        using (MySqlDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            int index = 1;

            while (dbReader.Read())
            {
                Session["Emer" + index.ToString()] = dbReader[0].ToString();

                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    dbConnection.Close();
}
```

You could also use a collection object like `List` and serialize this into the session.

Comment: i tried this but this skips 1st value . . i.e i got Session["Emer1"]=92 instead of 91 . .

Comment: @user1776428 that doesn't make any sense, maybe this is an ordering issue - try changing your query to `select EmerContact_id from [Table] order by EmerContact_id asc;`

Comment: @punter This will create a session for each ID, I think you should use one object (e.g. List, and store that in session) as I demonstrated below.  I know you've asked for multiple sessions, so this answer is more accurate - but, I think it would be better to use one session.

Answer (score 1):

You can store complete list or dataset in session, however its not recommended but you can do it.

When fetching you can cast it to the desired type.

Simple and easy

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question....

Please try this

```
string[] EmerContactList = new string[]{"Emer1","Emer2","Emer3"};
Session["values"] = EmerContactList ;
```

To access

```
string[] results= (string[])Session["values"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use one session object to store the values...

```
List<int> EmerContacts = new List<int>();

using (MySqlConnection dbConnection = new MySqlConnection("connectionstring"))
{
    using (MySqlCommand dbCommand = new MySqlCommand("select EmerContact_id from [Table];", dbConnection))
    {
        using (MySqlDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {

            while (dbReader.Read())
            {
                EmerContacts.Add((int)dbReader[0].ToString());

             }
        }
    }
}

Session["EmerContacts"] = EmerContacts;
```

When you need to use the list then, you can just convert the session back to List...

`List<int> myList = (List<int>)Session["EmerContacts"];`

**I hand typed some of it, so it may not compile, but you should get the gist of it.**

When you use this approach, you can then easily itterate over the collection.  Using your approach makes this a bit more difficult.